# How I can get PUID from mp3-file?

Tags: mp3, freebsd, puid

I want to streamline my library on FreeBsd using PUID from MusicBrainz. I need a command line utility for this, but I have not been able to find. It would be nice to give input mp3-file and receive PUID as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an app called GenPUID: http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/GenPUID

And it looks like it's in ports: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/audio/linux-genpuid/pkg-descr